# Format Money not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML Form:

```
<form id="zahlungsvereinbarung-rechnungen">
                <input type="checkbox" value="2400" name="rechnungen-pt[]" id="20011" onchange="addRemoveToPT();"><label>&nbsp; Rechnung: 20011 vom 01.02.2016 (Offen: 2.400,00)</label><br>                    </form>
```

This form is dynamically created (Sometimes more than one entry).

When I try to read the value out of this input field and convert it to a format Money value with this script:

```html
Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
var n = this, 
    c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, 
    d = d == undefined ? "." : d, 
    t = t == undefined ? "," : t, 
    s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", 
    i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", 
    j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
   return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
 };


function addRemoveToPT(re_nr, betrag)
{

//erst machen wir das Fenster zur Zahlungsmodalität wieder unsichtbar
document.getElementById("zahlungsmodalitaet_pt").style.display = "none";

//Jetzt schauen wir uns jede Checkbox an, welchen Wert sie hat
betragOpen = 0;
var elements = document.getElementById("zahlungsvereinbarung-rechnungen").elements["rechnungen-pt[]"];
if(elements.length > 1)
{
 
 for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
 {
 
  if(elements[i].value > 0 && elements[i].checked)
  {
   
   betragOpen += parseInt(elements[i].value);
   
  }
  
 
 }
 
}else
{
 
 betragOpen = elements.value;
 
}

if(betragOpen > 0)
{
 
 document.getElementById("betrag_pt_gesamt").innerHTML = betragOpen.formatMoney(2, ",", ".");
 document.getElementById("zahlungsmodalitaet_pt").style.display = "block";
 
}else
{
 
 document.getElementById("zahlungskonfiguration").style.display = "none";
 
}

}
```

I get an Error

```
betragOpen.formatMoney is not a function
```

I only get this error, if the List of input fields contain only one element. If there are more elements (even if I check only one element) its working.

Any Ideas?

Comment: where is your formatMoney() function.?

Comment: where is the PHP and jQuery part of this? Also IDs need to be unique. Change to `onclick="addRemoveToPT(this);"` and `function addRemoveToPT(checkbox)` to access the element in the form it lives in

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god - as soon as I post this I found the solution:

I forgot the parseInt in the "else" part... Here the code of the function where the problem was:

```html
function addRemoveToPT(re_nr, betrag)
{
 
 //erst machen wir das Fenster zur Zahlungsmodalität wieder unsichtbar
 document.getElementById("zahlungsmodalitaet_pt").style.display = "none";
 
 //Jetzt schauen wir uns jede Checkbox an, welchen Wert sie hat
 betragOpen = 0;
 var elements = document.getElementById("zahlungsvereinbarung-rechnungen").elements["rechnungen-pt[]"];
 if(elements.length > 1)
 {
  
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
  {
  
   if(elements[i].value > 0 && elements[i].checked)
   {
    
    betragOpen += parseInt(elements[i].value);
    
   }
   
  
  }
  
 }else
 {
  
  betragOpen = parseInt(elements.value);
  
 }
 
 if(betragOpen > 0)
 {
  
  document.getElementById("betrag_pt_gesamt").innerHTML = betragOpen.formatMoney(2, ",", ".");
  document.getElementById("zahlungsmodalitaet_pt").style.display = "block";
  
 }else
 {
  
  document.getElementById("zahlungskonfiguration").style.display = "none";
  
 }
 
}
```